Python giving me recursion error while using hugging face transformer pipeline
I am currently working on a project that uses the summarization pipeline provided by the hugging face transformers library. However, when I run the summarization function Python gives me an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/advikajain/Desktop/AI/with gui.py", line 2, in <module>
    from transformers import pipeline
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1412, in _handle_fromlist
  File "/Users/advikajain/Desktop/AI/coding/lib/python3.12/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 1593, in __getattr__
    module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/advikajain/Desktop/AI/coding/lib/python3.12/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py", line 1605, in _get_module
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.pipelines because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
maximum recursion depth exceeded

Here is my code:
summariser=pipeline('summarization',model="facebook/bart-large-cnn")
summarytext='summary not generated yet.'

def scrape():
  url=entry1.get()#entry1 here is a tkinter entry
  response=requests.get(url).text
  soup=BeautifulSoup(response,"html.parser")
  body=soup.body
  content=body.find_all('p')
  text=''' '''
  for p in content:
    text+=(p.text)
  return text

def summarise(summarizer=summariser,summarytext=summarytext):
  scrape()
  summary=summariser(text,max_length=100,min_length=30)
  summarytext=summary[0]['summary_text']
  finaltext=summarytext+'\n'+'\n'
  msg.insert(tkinter.END,summarytext)
  return summarytext

The function was supposed to run when the user pressed a Tkinter button,however no Tkinter window appears. I just get the error mentioned above.
kindly help.

Not linked to the error but as far as I can tell, the scape() line is useless because you don't save it's output to a variable. Also please post a [mre], right now none of the lines in the traceback are present in the code you posted. Btw if you have a folder/file named transformers in your current working directory, try renaming it

Does it freeze at _bootstrap._gcd_import()?
If so you may try to downgrade to Python 3.11.0 and rerun, it fixed my similar issue importing diffuser.

@TheLizzard Here you go:
link to the entire code - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rsR_roDJNspguXr03pAjwrhZFCZs0VC-/view?usp=sharing
the scrape function returns the text variable on which the summmarize function is executed.
